# Can a Vec cause a stackoverflow?

Tags: rust

```
let vector: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
```

Can the vector in the code above cause a stackoverflow if the vector grows too big?

```
let vector: Vec<Box<u8>> = Vec::new();
```

How bout this one? Since its elements are on the heap.

```
let vector: Box<Vec<u8>> = Box::new(Vec::new());
```

I'm assuming that in the code above no stackoverflow should be possible, am i correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No the actual data is on heap. So there will not be stack overflow.

What is on stack is capacity, length and the pointer to the actual data on heap. If regrowth is required then it is done on the heap. If it is moved (not cloned) then what is copied is just the length, capacity and pointer to data (bitwise shallow copy).

Not the actual implementation but if you have to implement Vector then you will start with:

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    ptr: Unique<T>,
    cap: usize,
    len: usize,
}
```

You see the `ptr` is actually pointing to heap location where the data is. The vector on stack will consists of just few fields like the 3 mentioned above.

You cannot grow an object on stack, as you push objects on stack frame if any object is allowed to grow it will run over other objects. On heap for growth, if contiguous memory is not available, then entire data is moved to another place with newer capacity; if contiguous memory block is available, then growth in capacity is instant.

Comment: *If it is moved or copied(not cloned) then what is copied is just the length, capacity and pointer to data (bitwise shallow copy).* - this sentence is incorrect, you cannot copy a `Vec`, only move it. A bitwise shallow copy of length/data/capacity triple would be horribly broken as it would incur a double free when both the copy and the original were dropped. (And even before that, it would break Rust's aliasing guarantees and much more.)

Comment: Yes, move is bitwise copy  so rust will not call Drop on moved from vec.

Comment: Edited removed explicit "copied" word as Vec does not implement Copy trait. So if Vec is included in a struct that tries to implement Copy trait, then compiler will complain.